# GetThreadContext replacement for Windows Store Apps and WP8+

Tags: .net, multithreading, winapi, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I'm using `GetThreadContext`/`SetThreadContext` right now in my application to switch execution context of a thread. This is a kind of lightweight threads implementation (more or less custom Fibers).

The main reason to use it is portability with `ucontext` from UNIX.

Now I'm about to port everything to Windows Store Apps and WP8+. I have checked, and these functions are not available for these platforms (as many others, like `CreateThread`).

The questions is basically following:
What are my options on light-weight threads or context switching (Best of all)?

Comment: The OS handles context switching for you. We aren't using Windows 3.1 any more.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, thanks! It's really helpful

Comment: Not sure if sarcastic... You don't have to worry about this most of the time. WSAs and WP apps are multithreaded by default via the Task async/await pattern.  Follow that, don't try to force some ancient threading paradigm in.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have any issue with Async/Await as threads replacement, but what I really need is co-routines. I Mean I want to switch context of current thread, do something else and later on resume the execution at the very same place. I don't want to do it in different thread, spawned by Async or anything else.

Comment: @Will, frankly I can not consider threading "ancient", it's rather low-level.

Comment: I didn't say threading was ancient, I said the **paradigm** you were forcing was. Nice of you to read that into my comment. And your requirements exactly describe what async/await does for you.  You should create a small prototype and see how it behaves.  Or, knock yourself out.  Your choice.

Comment: OK, thanks to everybody. As far as I understand there are no low-level option (correct me if I'm wrong) besides assembly.

Comment: I imagine that you won't be able to do this, because presumably it would break the sandbox.  (You could set the context to point at code whose safety hasn't been verified.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, could you explain in more details, please? Definitely you can point the context to even something invalid. My intension is to point it to some starting address (a function), though.

Comment: Sure, but how would Microsoft verify that your code only ever uses a valid address?  I'm not sure it would be possible, but even if it is, I doubt they'd be willing to go to the trouble.  NB: I may be mistaken, this is only based on my understanding of how the sandbox works from what I've read about it, I've never worked with it myself.  I'd just suggest that you look into it before putting a lot of work into that approach.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, sure, thanks for suggestion!